# Powershell : Find a group of text in a file then extract a specific line in that group of text

Tags: powershell

I've been on this for few days now, I'm trying to parse multiple text files containing data like this :

```
[Cluster1]
    GatewayIp=xx.xxx.xxx.xx
    IpAddress=xx.xxx.xxx.x
    MTU=0000
    NetMask=xxx.xxx.xxx.0
    Port=xxx
    Protocol=xxxx/xxxxx
    Sessions=xxxxxx
    Bands=xxx, xxx, x
    Binding=xxxxx
    GroupNumber=x
    InitQueue=xxxxxx
    Interface=xxxxxx
    Process=xxx
    SupportsCar=No
    SupportsCom=Yes
    SupportsPos=Yes
    SupportsXvd=No

[Cluster2]
    GatewayIp=xx.xxx.xxx.xx
    IpAddress=xx.xxx.xxx.x
    MTU=0000
    NetMask=xxx.xxx.xxx.0
    Port=xxx
    Protocol=xxxx/xxxxx
    Sessions=xxxxxx
    Bands=xxx, xxx, x
    Binding=xxxxx
    GroupNumber=x
    InitQueue=xxxxxx
    Interface=xxxxxx
    Process=xxx
    SupportsCar=No
    SupportsCom=No
    SupportsPos=No
    SupportsXvd=Yes
```

I want to extract the "IpAddress" in the section where thoses lines are present :

```
    SupportsCom=Yes
    SupportsPos=Yes
```

The thing is, I've tried using -context to grab the nth line after the section name "[Cluster1]", but that section name is different from file to file ...

```
$ip = Select-String -Path "$location" -Pattern "\[Cluster1\]" -Context 0,2 |
    Foreach-Object {$_.Context.PostContext}
```

I've tried using the Precontext to grab the Nth line before SupportsCom=Yes, but the line position of "IpAddress=" is different from file to file ...

```
$ip = Select-String -Path "$location" -Pattern "    SupportsCom=Yes" -Context 14,0 |
    Foreach-Object { $_.Line,$_.Context.PreContext[0].Trim()}
```

Is there a way to grab the section containing "SupportsCom=Yes" knowing that the section is delimited by a blank line above and below, then search in that section a string that contains "IpAddress=" then return the value afterthe "=" ?

Comment: That is INI format. Use a dedicated module for that instead of plain-text parsing like [PsIni](https://github.com/lipkau/PsIni)

Comment: At the moment I cannot install any modules, I'll have to make a request to the AD admin but it takes a long time to get an answer .... And the final script is meant to be used by L1 employees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since you are not allowed to use a module (perhaps later..), this should get you what you want

```
# change the extension in the Filter to match that of your files
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\somewhere' -Filter '*.ini' -File

$result = foreach ($file in $configFiles) {
    # initialize these variables to $null
    $IpAddress = $supportsCom = $supportsPos = $null
    # loop through the file line by line and try regex matches on them
    switch -Regex -File $file {
        '^\[([^\]]+)]' { 
            # did we get all wanted entries from the previous cluster?
            if ($IpAddress -and $supportsCom -and $supportsPos) {
                if ($supportsCom -eq 'Yes' -and $supportsPos -eq 'Yes') {
                    # just output the IpAddress so it gets collected in variable $result
                    $IpAddress
                }
                # reset the variables to $null
                $IpAddress = $supportsCom = $supportsPos = $null
            }
            # start a new cluster
            $cluster = $matches[1]
        }
        '^\s+IpAddress\s*=\s*(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})' { $IpAddress = $matches[1]}
        '^\s+SupportsCom\s*=\s*(Yes|No)' { $supportsCom = $matches[1] }
        '^\s+SupportsPos\s*=\s*(Yes|No)' { $supportsPos = $matches[1]}
    }
}

# show results on screen
$result

# or save as text file
$result | Set-Content -Path 'X:\somewhere\IpAddresses.txt'
```

Comment: Ok that works, the only thing is, I just want the IpAddress as an output not the cluster or filename, I'll put it in a csv column alongside other data that are easier to find.

Comment: @Olbrok Ok, I changed that. Now it outputs just the IpAddresses

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**

If you don't care about the name of the section(s), where `IpAddress` is found in, you can use this "one-liner" (broken into multiple lines for readability):

```
$ip = (Get-Content $location -Raw) -split '\[.+?\]' | 
    ConvertFrom-StringData | 
    Where-Object { $_.SupportsCom -eq 'Yes' -and $_.SupportsPos -eq 'Yes' } | 
    ForEach-Object IpAddress
```

- The `Get-Content` line reads the input file as a single multi-line string and [splits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7.2) it at the section headers (e. g. `[Cluster1]`).
- [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata?view=powershell-7.2) converts the `Key = Value` lines into one `hashtable` per section.
- For each hashtable, `Where-Object` checks whether it contains `SupportsCom=Yes` and `SupportsPos=Yes`
- `ForEach-Object IpAddress` is shorthand for writing `Select-Object -ExpandProperty IpAddress` which gives you the actual value of `IpAddress` instead of an object that contains a member named `IpAddress`.
- Note that `$ip` can be either a single string value or an array of strings (if there are multiple matching sections).

---

**Original answer:**

You could also write a general-purpose function that converts INI sections into objects. This enables you to use the pipeline with a simple `Where-Object` statement to get the data you are interested in.

Generic function to output INI sections as objects, one by one:

```
Function Read-IniObjects {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)] [String] $Path
    )

    process {
        $section = @{}   # A hashtable that stores all properties of the currently processed INI section.

        # Read file line by line and match each line by the given regular expressions.
        switch -File $Path -RegEx { 
            '^\s*\[(.+?)\]\s*$' {               # [SECTION]
                # Output all data of previous section
                if( $section.Count ) { [PSCustomObject] $section }

                # Create new section data
                $section = [ordered] @{ IniSection = $matches[ 1 ] }
            }
            '^\s*(.+?)\s*=\s*(.+?)\s*$' {        # KEY = VALUE
                $key, $value = $matches[ 1..2 ]
                $section.$key = $value
            }
        }
        
        # Output all data of last section
        if( $section.Count ) { [PSCustomObject] $section }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$ip = Read-IniObjects 'test.ini' |
    Where-Object { $_.SupportsCom -eq 'Yes' -and $_.SupportsPos -eq 'Yes' } | 
    ForEach-Object IpAddress
```

**Notes:**

- The INI file is parsed using the [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) statement, which can directly use a file as input. This is much faster than using a `Get-Content` loop.
- As we are using `-RegEx` parameter, the switch statement matches each line of the file to the given regular expressions, entering the case branches only if the current line matches.
- Get detailed explanation about how the RegEx's work:

  - match lines like `[Section]` -> [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/cVxE5a/1)
  - match lines like `Key = Value` -> [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/MyTOxy/1)
- `ForEach-Object IpAddress` is shorthand for writing `Select-Object -ExpandProperty IpAddress` which gives you the actual value of `IpAddress` instead of an object that contains a member named `IpAddress`.
- Note that `$ip` can be either a single string value or an array of strings (if there are multiple matching sections).